# Conditional variance: How did the author get from $\text{Var}(Y | X) = E((Y - E(Y | X))^2 | X)$ to $\text{Var}(Y | X) = E(Y^2 | X) - (E(Y | X))^2$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, variance

My textbook, *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang, says the following in a section on **conditional variance**:

> **Definition 9.5.1** (Conditional variance). The *conditional variance of $Y$ given $X$* is
>
> $$\text{Var}(Y | X) = E((Y - E(Y | X))^2 | X).$$
>
> This is equivalent to
>
> $$\text{Var}(Y | X) = E(Y^2 | X) - (E(Y | X))^2.$$

I now attempt to expand $E((Y - E(Y | X))^2 | X)$:

> $$\begin{align} E((Y - E(Y | X))^2 | X) &= E((Y^2 - 2YE(Y | X) + E(Y | X)^2) | X) \\ &= E((Y^2 | X - 2YE(Y | X) + E(Y | X)^2) \end{align}$$

So I have two questions about this:

1. In the above, I assumed that $|X$ is distributive; is this valid?
2. I wasn't completely sure of how to use the linearity property of expected values here; specifically, for the $- 2YE(Y | X)$ term of the expression. How is it correctly done? Naively, I would have proceeded as follows: $E((Y^2 | X - 2YE(Y | X) + E(Y | X)^2) = E(Y^2 | X) - 2 E(YE(Y | X)) + E(Y | X)^2$ (since the expected value of an expected value is just the expected value); does this seem correct, or have am I doing something incorrectly (if so, then what is my misunderstanding)?

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance#Explanation,_relation_to_least-squares) for conditional variance has the following:

> $$\begin{align}
> \operatorname{E}[ (Y-f(X))^2 ]
> &= \operatorname{E}[                   (Y-\operatorname{E}(Y|X)\,\,+\,\,  \operatorname{E}(Y|X)-f(X) )^2 ] \\
> &= \operatorname{E}[ \operatorname{E}\{ (Y-\operatorname{E}(Y|X)\,\,+\,\,  \operatorname{E}(Y|X)-f(X) )^2|X\} ] \\
> &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}( Y| X )] + \operatorname{E}[(\operatorname{E}(Y|X)-f(X))^2]\,.
> \end{align}$$

But this seems different to what was presented in the textbook, so I'm also struggling to see how this result was obtained, and how it relates to the one in the textbook.

So, I guess the third question would be:

3. How did the author get from $\text{Var}(Y | X) = E((Y - E(Y | X))^2 | X)$ to $\text{Var}(Y | X) = E(Y^2 | X) - (E(Y | X))^2$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Why are you transferring the random variable $X - 2 Y \Bbb E (Y \vert X) + \Bbb E(Y\vert X)^2$ into a condition. This makes no sense. $\Bbb E (Y\vert X)$ is a $X$-measurable random variable. Just treat it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding the square 
$$
E((Y-E(Y|X))^2|X) = E(Y^2 - 2E(Y|X)Y + E(Y|X)^2|X),
$$
Now you have $E(E(Y|X)^2|X) = E(Y|X)^2$ as $E(Y|X)$ is measurable w.r.t. the sigma algebra generated by $X$, and so is $E(Y|X)^2$. Moreover $E(ZY|X) = ZE(Y|X)$ if $Z$ is measurable w.r.t. the sigma algebra generated by $X$, and if you use this with $Z = E(Y|X)$ you get $E(E(Y|X)Y|X) = E(Y|X)^2$. Therefore, by linearity of conditional expectations,
$$
E((Y-E(Y|X))^2|X) = E(Y^2|X) - 2E(Y|X)^2 + E(Y|X)^2 = E(Y^2|X) - E(Y|X)^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The explanation for how you got $E(E(Y|X)Y|X) = E(Y|X)^2$ is unclear to me. Can you please clarify further, without using measure theory terminology (since I haven't studied measure theory yet)? I found the property $E(ZY|X) = ZE(Y|X)$ (assuming $Z$ is a random variable?) and the subsequent $E(E(Y|X)Y|X) = E(Y|X)^2$ perplexing.

Comment: The quantity $E(Y|X)$ is a random variable (r.v.), therefore $Z = E(Y|X)$, with $Z$ a r.v., is a valid writing. The property $E(ZY|X) = ZE(Y|X)$ for $Z$ a r.v. which is $X$-measurable is a standard property of the conditional expectation. Moreover $E(Y|X)$ is $X$-measurable by definition of the conditional expectation. Therefore $E(ZY|X) = E(E(Y|X)Y|X) = E(Y|X) \cdot E(Y|X) = E(Y|X)^2$.

Comment: The property here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties is denoted "pulling out known factors". Its proof is not totally trivial, and is obtained going through sequences of simple r.v.'s (steps) and taking the limit for a general r.v.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to prove the equivalent writings of the conditional variance without going through this property of the conditional expectation. The concept of measurability has to be known in order to even define random variables!

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\Bbb E[(Y-\Bbb E[Y\mid X])^2\mid X]&=\Bbb E[Y^2-2Y\Bbb E[Y\mid X]+\Bbb E[Y\mid X]^2\mid X]\\&=\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-2\Bbb E[Y\Bbb E[Y\mid X]\mid X]+\Bbb E[\Bbb E[Y\mid X]^2\mid X]\\&=\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-2\Bbb E[Y\mid X]\Bbb E[Y\mid X]+\Bbb E[\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-\Bbb V[Y\mid X]\mid X]\\&=\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-2(\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-\Bbb V[Y\mid X])+\Bbb E[Y^2\mid X]-\Bbb V[Y\mid X]\\&=\Bbb V[Y\mid X].\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So we **can** treat $| X$ is as distributive?

Comment: It is distributive within $\Bbb E$ afaik. This is because, due to linearity, $\Bbb E[A+B\mid C]=\Bbb E[A\mid C]+\Bbb E[B\mid C]$.