# Conditional variance of the convolution of two R.V.?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $X,Z \sim U[0,1]$ independent. I want to compute the conditional variance of $Y=X+Z$. 
First, I notice that $$f(y) = \begin{cases}
y & \text{for $0 < y < 1$} \\
2-y & \text{for $1 \le y < 2$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

And that $E[Y|X]=1/2+X$. I think I may compute the conditional variance as follows: $$E[(Y-E(Y|X))^2|X)=E[Y^2+E(Y|X)^2-2YE(Y|X)|X]=...$$ using linearity of expectations etc. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Since $\mathbb E(X + Z \mid X) = X + \mathbb E(Z) = X + 1/2$, the definition of the conditional variance gives
$$\mathbb E((X + Z - X - 1/2)^2 \mid X) =
\mathbb E((Z - 1/2)^2) =
1/12.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\text{Var}(Y\mid X)=E(Y^2\mid X)-E(Y\mid X)^2.
$$
See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413489/conditional-variance-how-did-the-author-get-from-textvary-x-ey-e?rq=1). As you noted
$$
E(Y\mid X)=X+E(Z\mid X)=X+EZ=X+1/2
$$
by linearity and independence of $X$ and Z. Moreover
$$
\begin{align}
E(Y^2\mid X)&=E(X^2+2XZ+Z^2\mid X)\\
&=X^2+2XE(Z\mid X)+E(Z^2\mid X)\\
&=X^2+2XEZ+EZ^2\\
&=X^2+X+\frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
$$
where we used independence of $X$ and $Z$ together with the pull-out property in the third line.
So
$$
\text{Var}(Y\mid X)=X^2+X+\frac{1}{3}-\left(X+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2
$$